# What augmented reality packages can be integrated with flutter, to create an augmented reality environment when reading a QR code?

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, flutter-dependencies, arcore, wikitude

I am making a pet registration flutter application, which consists of storing each registration in a QR code dynamically, additionally I want to create an augmented reality environment when reading these QR codes, and throw the information of the mascot.
Maybe there is an augmented reality package that integrates with flutter and allows me to continue moving forward with the project.

Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Have you tried https://pub.dev/packages/arkit_plugin?

Comment: and for android https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak This package that you recommend if it allows me to read dynamic QR codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (ar_core) package to implement augmented reality in your project
https://pub.dev/packages/ar_core